# How to convert two character columns to a binary matrix?

Tags: r

Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C"), y=c("m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r"))
df
  x y
1 A m
2 A n
3 B o
4 C p
5 C q
6 C r
```

What I wanted is to convert it to a binary matrix using `y` as rowname and `unique(x)` as colname:

```
  A B C
m 1 0 0
n 1 0 0
o 0 1 0
p 0 0 1
q 0 0 1
r 0 0 1
```

My first thought is to use `tidyr::spread()` but seems not properly working.

Comment: Is it possible to have e.g. `A m` for one row and `B m` for another? if so, would row `m` in the intended matrix be `1 1 0` (assuming no row `C m` in the original matrix)?

Comment: how about `t(table(df))`?

Comment: @Ben `x` and `y` may have duplicate combinations, so `table()` will create numbers greater than 1.

Comment: Easy to fix: `result[result>0] = 1`

Comment: @Ben but it drops the information of those duplicates. Of course it depends on OP's goal.

Comment: @DarrenTsai I understand what you mean...and I agree, a lot depends on OP goal as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(y,
              names_from = x, 
              values_from = x, 
              values_fn = list(x = length), 
              values_fill = list(x = 0))


  y         A     B     C
  <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 m         1     0     0
2 n         1     0     0
3 o         0     1     0
4 p         0     0     1
5 q         0     0     1
6 r         0     0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
library(tidyverse)

df<-data.frame(x=c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C"), y=c("m", "n", "o", "p", "q", 
"r"))

df %>% 
  mutate(x=str_split(x, ",")) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  mutate(dummy=1) %>% 
  spread(x, dummy, fill=0)
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C
m   1   0   0   
n   1   0   0   
o   0   1   0   
p   0   0   1   
q   0   0   1   
r   0   0   1
```

Comment: Why are you calling `str_split` like this on a vector that isn't actually comma-delimited?

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution.

```
cbind(df[-1], +sapply(unique(df$x), `==`, df$x))

#   y A B C
# 1 m 1 0 0
# 2 n 1 0 0
# 3 o 0 1 0
# 4 p 0 0 1
# 5 q 0 0 1
# 6 r 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `table` in `base R`

```
+(t(table(df)) > 0)
```